# Variable that is defined/evaluated each time it is called

Tags: javascript

I have an object, eg:

```
var myObject = 
    {
       data1 : null,
       data2 : null,
       value : null,
    }
```

I would like `value : null` to be  defined analogus to a function, except that it will return a value when i, for example, call `console.log(myObject.value)`, as opposed to calling `console.log(myObject.value())`.

How would this be done?

The goal is for, on calling `myObject.value`, a function to evaluate and return something. eg:

```
 function(){
    return this.data1 + "||" + this.data2;
 }
```

The purpose is to be able to treat the value of this element as if it were a static variable; however, because the value of the object depends on two properties that may change, it would be preferable to have the value be re-evaluated each time on calling it.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript getter properties are accessed as normal properties, but they evaluate as functions each time they are accessed.

Here are two ways to define them:

**Using `get` keyword:**

```
var myObject = {
    data1: 0,
    data2: 1,
    get value() {
        return this.data1 + '||' + this.data2;
    }
};
console.log( myObject.value ); // prints '0||1' to console
```

From developer.mozilla.org:

> The get syntax binds an object property to a function that will be called when that property is looked up.
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get

**Using `defineProperty()`:**

```
var myObject = {
    data1: 0,
    data2: 1,
};
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "value", {
    get: function() { return this.data + '||' + this.data2; }
});
console.log( myObject.value ); // prints '0||1' to console
```

Comment: If you're interested in a getter, you may also be interested in a setter. Works exactly as your intuition would tell you. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Answer (score 4):

Define a property with a getter.

```
Object.defineProperty(myObject, "value", {
  get: function() { return this.data + '||' + this.data2; }
});
```

Comment: You rock! Do you know if there is anyway to define that `var myObject = { /* here */}` ?

Comment: @VladK there is, `object = { _i : 0, get propertyName() { return this._i++; } }` check out my answer for example